# How to fix the 'numpy.int' attribute error when using skopt.BayesSearchCV in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, scikit-optimize, bayessearchcv

When I run the following code on the official documentation, it has an error.

[Minimal example](https://scikit-optimize.github.io/stable/auto_examples/sklearn-gridsearchcv-replacement.html)

```py
from skopt import BayesSearchCV
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X, y = load_digits(n_class=10, return_X_y=True)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.75, test_size=.25, random_state=0)

# log-uniform: understand as search over p = exp(x) by varying x
opt = BayesSearchCV(
    SVC(),
    {
        'C': (1e-6, 1e+6, 'log-uniform'),
        'gamma': (1e-6, 1e+1, 'log-uniform'),
        'degree': (1, 8),  # integer valued parameter
        'kernel': ['linear', 'poly', 'rbf'],  # categorical parameter
    },
    n_iter=32,
    cv=3
)

opt.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

The last line produces an error:

> **AttributeError**
> module 'numpy' has no attribute 'int'.
> `np.int` was a deprecated alias for the builtin `int`. To avoid this error in existing code, use `int` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. When replacing `np.int`, you may wish to use e.g. `np.int64` or `np.int32` to specify the precision. If you wish to review your current use, check the release note link for additional information.
> The aliases was originally deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance see the original release note at:
> https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations

How can I solve this problem? Are there other ways to implement Bayesian search?

Perhaps the version of skopt is too old. Are there other ways to implement Bayesian search? Besides grid search, random search, and bayes search, is there any other way to help me choose the hyperparameters of the machine learning model?

Comment: do you want to accept an answer that resolved your issue ?

Answer (score 10):

I managed to resolve this by simply adding this line before calling .fit()

```
opt = BayesSearchCV(...)

np.int = int
opt.fit(...)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

It's not clear which line of code is raising the exception but I suspect the culprit is skopt not having caught up with the full deprecation of `np.int` in numpy. You could downgrade numpy to `<1.24` or this change could do:
from

```py
        'degree': (1, 8),  # integer valued parameter
```

to

```py
        'degree': np.arange(1,9),
```

to pass the integer dimension as a array of integer.

Edit: I found this ongoing [MR](https://github.com/scikit-optimize/scikit-optimize/pull/1166) to fix the issue

Comment: In fact it's the line `opt.fit()` that raises the error. More precisely, `BayesSearchCV.fit()` uses `np.int`. I replaced all `np.int` with `int` in the file 'site-packages\skopt\space\transformers.py' according to the link you provided. The code seems to be working well. thanks a lot.

Comment: Arrrf, I wished you did not have to update the package itself but... whatever works! skopt has not been updated since late 2021 looks like it won't get the fix any time soon. Glad I could help. You may want to post your fix as an answer and validate asap

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error while trying to fit BayesSearchCV

```
BayesSearchCV(
            SVR(),
            param_distributions,
            n_iter,
            cv,
            scoring,
            random_state,
            n_jobs).fit(X_train, y_train).
```

> AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'int'.

As @sanctus suggested:

1. Replaced all `np.int` with `int` in the file
   ***'anaconda3\envs\myenv\Lib\site-packages\skopt\space\transformers.py'***
2. Restarted kernel, or in my case exited pycharm app and opened again
3. run the code again and error fixed.

Answer (score 0):

`

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

param_space = {
    'n_estimators': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500],
    'learning_rate': [0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5],
    'max_depth': [3, 5, 7, 9, 11],
    'reg_alpha': [0.1, 0.3, 0.5],
    'reg_lambda': [0.1, 0.3, 0.5]
}
# Create the XGBoost model
model = XGBClassifier()

bayes_search = BayesSearchCV(
    estimator=model,
    search_spaces=param_space,
    scoring='f1_macro',
    cv=3,
    n_jobs=-1,
    n_iter=50,  
    random_state=42
)
# added this line to my code
np.int = int

bayes_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

` JUST ADD THE ABOVE LINE TO THE CODE IT WORKS

Comment: i see the same answer has been proposed by the user Narayan a couple of months ago.